# Get user id from mention using discord.ext in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try to run the command `$getUserId @user` using the below code, and try to print it, I get the @mention username as a string and not the user's id:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@client.command()
async def getUserId(ctx, *arg):
if not arg:
    userId = ctx.author.id
else:
    userId = arg.id
await ctx.send(userId)
```

I could not find good documentation on finding the id from a given mention without using `on_message(message)`. I have had luck using `async def getUserId(ctx, user: Discord.user)` and importing discord itself, but this causes an error when I just run `$getUserId`

How would I go about approaching this having: the mentioned user as a parameter and handling all exceptions when the `$getUserId` command is given
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make something like that :

```
@bot.command()
async def get_userId(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(user.id)
```

for the firt you need mention your user
or you can get like this

```
@bot.command()
async def get_userId(ctx, user:discord.User):
    user_id = user.id
    get_user_id = bot.get_user(user_id)
    await ctx.send(get_user_id)
```

Comment: I completely forgot about optional arguments.
Doing `get_userId(ctx, *user: discord.User)` with `import discord` works great. Thank you!

Comment: Extended the question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188833/get-user-id-from-mention-in-discord-py