# Get user id from mention in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try to run the command `$getUserId @user` using the below code, it works as intended but gives an error when something like `$getUserId 123` is sent when trying to pass the parameter.
I want to have a bot that does not give any errors.

```
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@client.command()
async def getUserId(ctx, *user: discord.User):
if not arg:
    userId = ctx.author.id
else:
    userId = arg.id
await ctx.send(userId)
```

How would I go about approaching this having: the mentioned user as a parameter and handling all exceptions when the `$getUserId` command is given?

OR

Is there an easier approach to get the user's id from a mention? There has to be an easy way to do this, right?
Anyways, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if  it was a mistake in the question or the code but your indents are messed up and arg doesn't exist

```py
def convert_mention_to_id(mention):
    return int(mention[1:][:len(mention)-2].replace("@","").replace("!",""))

@client.command(name="getUserId")
async def getUserId(ctx ,*arg):
    if not arg:
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.id)
    else:
        try:
            await ctx.send({i:convert_mention_to_id(arg[i]) for i in arg})
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send("Invalid ID")
```

convert_mention_to_id is a utility function, mentions are passed in `<@!id>` format the function simply gets id from it.

The ID is used in the discord API as int so it is converted in the function which raises value error when invalid id is passed

And you can get the mentioned user with [client.get_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) but it needs the member intents to be true

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. **Using arg**: You do not define `arg` anywhere in the code you provided. Instead, replace arg with user.
2. **if not user**: If you were to leave user blank, you would have raised an error such as "user is a required argument that is missing." One way to combat this would be to default it to `None`.

You can review the above observations in the code below, as well as the tested example.

```py
@client.command()
async def getUserId(ctx, user: discord.User=None): # defaults user to None if nothing is passed
    if not user: # you are not using an arg variable, you're using user
        userId = ctx.author.id
    else:
        userId = user.id # same as previous
    await ctx.send(userId)
```

[image: Code working]